# django redirect url concatenating to the previous url, help me to stop concatenating

Tags: django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

this is my previouse url - http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewbook/8/viewchapter/57/

this is the url I want to redirect - http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewbook/8/viewchapter/57/

but its redirect me to this url - http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewbook/8/viewchapter/57/

project - urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
]
```

home.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('viewbook/<int:id>/', views.viewbook , name='viewbook'),
    path('viewchapter/<int:id>/', views.viewchapter , name='viewchapter'),
    path('viewpost/<int:id>/', views.viewpost , name='viewpost'),
]
```

views.py

```
def viewbook(response , id):
    book = Book.objects.get(id = id)
    allchapters = Chapter.objects.all()
    chapters = []
    for chapt in allchapters:
        if chapt.Book.id == book.id:
            chapters.append(chapt)
    inputform = ChapterForm()
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = ChapterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            chapt = Chapter(Book = book , chapterNum = response.POST['chapterNum'] , chapterText = "")
            print(chapt)
            chapt.save()
            print(Chapter.objects.get(id= chapt.id))
            return redirect('viewchapter/%i/' %chapt.id)
    inputform.fields["chapterNum"].initial =len(chapters) + 1
    context = {
        'book' : book,
        'form' : inputform,
        'chapters' : chapters
        
    }
    return render(response , 'viewbook.html' , context)


def viewchapter(response , id):
    chapter = Chapter.objects.get(id = id)
    context = {'chapter' : chapter}
    return render(response , 'viewchapter.html', context)
```

I think the problem is with this line

return redirect('viewchapter/%i/' %chapt.id)

I change it to
return HttpResponseRedirect('viewchapter/%i/' %chapt.id)

but bith of them are giving me same result like this

The current path, viewbook/9/viewchapter/58/, didn’t match any of these.

Comment: The 3 example urls you have provided are identical. Please correct them in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems detected:

- relative URL which can be fixed with leading `/` in `redirect` call
- `redirect` function is used not in *django way*

Redirect can accept hardcoded URLs however in your case view name with arguments should be passed. As [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) say redirect can accept view or URL pattern name and arguments:

`return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')`

URL will be built by reversing URL pattern you defined in urls.py

In your case it will be

`return redirect('viewchapter', chapt.id)`

or

`return redirect('viewchapter', id=chapt.id)`

Comment: thank you sir, I have corrected my code with this solution,    relative URL which can be fixed with leading / in redirect call